# Basic R: Multiplying elements in 3-D array with loop

Tags: arrays, r, linear-algebra, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

I have two 3-D arrays, **A** and **B**, each 2 x 3 x 3.  Examples shown below (which will help clarify how I'd like to multiply).

```
 A1   A2   A3                             B1   B2   B3  
 A4   A5   A6                             B4   B5   B6

 A7   A8   A9                             B7   B8   B9
 A10  A11  A12                            B10  B11  B12

 A13  A14  A15                            B13  B14  B15
 A16  A17  A18                            B16  B17  B18
```

What I want to do is create a matrix where the 3 **A** matrices are averaged and the value at a location is weighted by the corresponding **B** value...I can't explain well, but for example, the first element is:

```
[(A1*B1)+(A7*B7)+(A13*B13)] / sum(B1,B7,B13).
```

Another element is:

```
[(A5*B5)+(A11*B11)+(A17*B17)] / sum(B5,B11,B17).
```

and so on...the result is a 2 x 3 matrix.  I've been playing with different combinations of nested for loops, an example of which is shown below, but I haven't figured out how to do it properly... help appreciated.

```
for (j in 1:2){
     for (k in 1:3){
          ans[j*k]=sum(A[j,k,1:3]*B[j,k,1:3])/sum(B[j,k,1:3])
     }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
apply(A * B, c(1,2), sum) / apply(B, c(1,2), sum)
```

Comment: @chriscolose, I was happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted; you can follow the instructions at http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just re-write your expression:

```
for (j in 1:2){
     for (k in 1:3){
          ans[j,k]= dotProduct(A[k,j],B[k,j])/sum(B[k,j])
     }
}
```

Comment: @flodel's solution is much more in keeping with "best practice" R.